# How to add rel="nofollow" to links with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The function below is designed to apply `rel="nofollow"` attributes to all external links and no internal links unless the path matches a predefined root URL defined as `$my_folder` below.

So given the variables...

```
$my_folder = 'http://localhost/mytest/go/';
$blog_url = 'http://localhost/mytest';
```

And the content...

```
<a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>

<a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator">internal cloaked link</a>

<a href="http://cnn.com">external</a>
```

The end result, after replacement should be...

```
<a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>

<a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator" rel="nofollow">internal cloaked link</a>

<a href="http://cnn.com" rel="nofollow">external</a>
```

Notice that the first link is not altered, since its an internal link.

The link on the second line is also an internal link, but since it matches our `$my_folder` string, it gets the `nofollow` too.

The third link is the easiest, since it does not match the `blog_url`, its obviously an external link.

However, in the script below, ALL of my links are getting `nofollow`. How can I fix the script to do what I want?

```
function save_rseo_nofollow($content) {
$my_folder =  $rseo['nofollow_folder'];
$blog_url = get_bloginfo('url');
    preg_match_all('~<a.*>~isU',$content["post_content"],$matches);
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){
        if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i])
            && (preg_match('~' . $my_folder . '~', $matches[0][$i]) 
               || !preg_match( '~'.$blog_url.'~',$matches[0][$i]))){
            $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
            $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
            $content["post_content"] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content["post_content"]);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I think DOMDocument would be nicer to use with this.

Comment: @alex: dont get me started, LOL. I'm sure it would be but everytime I've tried it, I've got 4 times more code and it never works exactly right. At least I can get the preg_match to work, but it needs some minor tweaks. But I'm not against giving DOMdocument another shot if someone can crack the question with a DOMdocument example that works on the WordPress content editor's post_content object.

Comment: Try phpQuery rather than cumbersome DOMDocument. But at this point it should also not go unmentioned that deploying `rel=nofollow` is quite pointless. It does not help with your or anyone elses spam problem. It's just free labour so Google has less work. It's not known to be a deterrant for spambots either.

Comment: @Scott B I posted a DOMDocument solution that works. :)

Comment: @mario I agree that DOMDocument is cumbersome. I might check out this phpQuery sometime soon, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: preg_replace_callback does just fine. No need for crazy objects or lots of strpos calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to make it more readable first, and only afterwards make your `if` rules more complex:

```
function save_rseo_nofollow($content) {
    $content["post_content"] =
    preg_replace_callback('~<(a\s[^>]+)>~isU', "cb2", $content["post_content"]);
    return $content;
}

function cb2($match) { 
    list($original, $tag) = $match;   // regex match groups

    $my_folder =  "/hostgator";       // re-add quirky config here
    $blog_url = "http://localhost/";

    if (strpos($tag, "nofollow")) {
        return $original;
    }
    elseif (strpos($tag, $blog_url) && (!$my_folder || !strpos($tag, $my_folder))) {
        return $original;
    }
    else {
        return "<$tag rel='nofollow'>";
    }
}
```

Gives following output:

```
[post_content] =>
  <a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>
  <a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator" rel=nofollow>internal cloaked link</a>    
  <a href="http://cnn.com" rel=nofollow>external</a>
```

The problem in your original code might have been $rseo which wasn't declared anywhere.

Comment: @Mario: Got it. Thanks. How would you encapsulate the rel attribs in quotes? rel="nofollow" to validate?

Comment: @Scott: Use `return "<$tag rel=\"nofollow\">";` or inner single quotes instead.

Comment: @mario: what does the & in front of the arg $content do? function(&$content)

Comment: @Scott: Passes a reference. But I just noticed you need an `return` instead. See edit.

Comment: @mario: WP errors on the & in front of content so I removed it. Now get > Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampplite\htdocs\mysite\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1222

Comment: @Mario: are you returning content or just setting it to a value in save_rseo_nofollow()? Don't I need to return it replaced?

Comment: @Scott: See previous edit. WP still needs the `return`. The array content gets updated right before the return.

Comment: @Mario - got it. +1 Works flawlessly so far. Let me put it through some fire.

Comment: @Scott: There's one thing that can be optimized still. The regex should be `<(a\s[^>]+)>` or `a\b[` to not trip over any `<abbr>` tags etc.

Comment: @Mario - the no_follow_folder may or may not be set. If its not set, that branch should be ignored. I'm pulling that variable from a settings array declared outside the function. Should I just pass it in as an arg? I'm calling it with add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'save_rseo_nofollow' );

Comment: @Scott: See edit for a possible solution. You cannot pull in arguments there because it's a callback. If it is a configuration variable you could use `global $my_folder;` or something alike. Or simply prepend more `elseif` branches for your special cases.

Comment: @Mario - how to code exception when my_folder is empty (not set)? if/then? Also, $my_folder is absolute, not relative as in your ex. Code change?

Comment: @Mario - got it. Flawless but for one exception. When my_folder set but get_option('nofollow') is not. Still want to nofollow internal cloaked, but not external in that case.

Comment: @Scott: Add more `if` blocks then to keep it readable. My support ends here, I'm not writing the whole plugin for you.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the DOMDocument solution...

```
$str = '<a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>

<a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator">internal cloaked link</a>

<a href="http://cnn.com" rel="me">external</a>

<a href="http://google.com">external</a>

<a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">external</a>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" rel="junk in the rel">external</a>
';
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->preserveWhitespace = FALSE;

$dom->loadHTML($str);

$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$host = strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ':');

foreach($a as $anchor) {
        $href = $anchor->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;

        if (preg_match('/^https?:\/\/' . preg_quote($host, '/') . '/', $href)) {
           continue;
        }

        $noFollowRel = 'nofollow';
        $oldRelAtt = $anchor->attributes->getNamedItem('rel');

        if ($oldRelAtt == NULL) {
            $newRel = $noFollowRel;
        } else {
            $oldRel = $oldRelAtt->nodeValue;
            $oldRel = explode(' ', $oldRel);
            if (in_array($noFollowRel, $oldRel)) {
                continue;
            }
            $oldRel[] = $noFollowRel;
            $newRel = implode($oldRel,  ' ');
        }

        $newRelAtt = $dom->createAttribute('rel');
        $noFollowNode = $dom->createTextNode($newRel);
        $newRelAtt->appendChild($noFollowNode);
        $anchor->appendChild($newRelAtt);

}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

#### Output

```
string(509) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>

<a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator">internal cloaked link</a>

<a href="http://cnn.com" rel="me nofollow">external</a>

<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">external</a>

<a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">external</a>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" rel="junk in the rel nofollow">external</a>
</body></html>
"
```

Comment: sweet. checking it out now. Thanks for really attacking the question.

Answer (score 10):

Try this one (PHP 5.3+):

- skip selected address
- allow manually set rel parameter

and code:

```
function nofollow($html, $skip = null) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "#(<a[^>]+?)>#is", function ($mach) use ($skip) {
            return (
                !($skip && strpos($mach[1], $skip) !== false) &&
                strpos($mach[1], 'rel=') === false
            ) ? $mach[1] . ' rel="nofollow">' : $mach[0];
        },
        $html
    );
}
```

Examples:

```
echo nofollow('<a href="link somewhere" rel="something">something</a>');
// will be same because it's already contains rel parameter

echo nofollow('<a href="http://www.cnn.com">something</a>'); // ad
// add rel="nofollow" parameter to anchor

echo nofollow('<a href="http://localhost">something</a>', 'localhost');
// skip this link as internall link
```

Comment: so what could be done to make it replace an existing rel?

Comment: thanks for this solution. What if I want to pass an array of skipping list of domains how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions to do this job properly would be quite complicated. It would be easier to use an actual parser, such as the one from the [DOM extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). DOM isn't very beginner-friendly, so what you can do is load the HTML with DOM then run the modifications with [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). They're backed by the same library, so it's easy to use one with the other.

Here's how it can look like:

```
$my_folder = 'http://localhost/mytest/go/';
$blog_url = 'http://localhost/mytest';

$html = '<html><body>
<a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>
<a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator">internal cloaked link</a>
<a href="http://cnn.com">external</a>
</body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

// grab all <a> nodes with an href attribute
foreach ($sxe->xpath('//a[@href]') as $a)
{
    if (substr($a['href'], 0, strlen($blog_url)) === $blog_url
     && substr($a['href'], 0, strlen($my_folder)) !== $my_folder)
    {
        // skip all links that start with the URL in $blog_url, as long as they
        // don't start with the URL from $my_folder;
        continue;
    }

    if (empty($a['rel']))
    {
        $a['rel'] = 'nofollow';
    }
    else
    {
        $a['rel'] .= ' nofollow';
    }
}

$new_html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $new_html;
```

As you can see, it's really short and simple. Depending on your needs, you may want to use `preg_match()` in place of the `strpos()` stuff, for example:

```
    // change the regexp to your own rules, here we match everything under
    // "http://localhost/mytest/" as long as it's not followed by "go"
    if (preg_match('#^http://localhost/mytest/(?!go)#', $a['href']))
    {
        continue;
    }
```

---

#### Note

I missed the last code block in the OP when I first read the question. The code I posted (and basically any solution based on DOM) is better suited at processing a whole page rather than a HTML block. Otherwise, DOM will attempt to "fix" your HTML and may add a `<body>` tag, a DOCTYPE, etc...

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your code but the its still adding nofollow to the blog url. any help?

Comment: This code helped me, but I did run into an encoding issue when the `$html` string contained utf-8 characters such as curly quotes. Replacing `$dom->loadHTML($html);` with `$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));` fixed the issue. Source of fix: [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/3059883)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @alex for your nice solution. But, I was having a problem with Japanese text. I have fixed it as following way. Also, this code can skip multiple domains with the `$whiteList` array.

```
public function addRelNoFollow($html, $whiteList = [])
{
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    /** @var \DOMElement $anchor */
    foreach ($a as $anchor) {
        $href = $anchor->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;
        $domain = parse_url($href, PHP_URL_HOST);

        // Skip whiteList domains
        if (in_array($domain, $whiteList, true)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Check & get existing rel attribute values
        $noFollow = 'nofollow';
        $rel = $anchor->attributes->getNamedItem('rel');
        if ($rel) {
            $values = explode(' ', $rel->nodeValue);
            if (in_array($noFollow, $values, true)) {
                continue;
            }
            $values[] = $noFollow;
            $newValue = implode($values, ' ');
        } else {
            $newValue = $noFollow;
        }

        // Create new rel attribute
        $rel = $dom->createAttribute('rel');
        $node = $dom->createTextNode($newValue);
        $rel->appendChild($node);
        $anchor->appendChild($rel);
    }

    // There is a problem with saveHTML() and saveXML(), both of them do not work correctly in Unix.
    // They do not save UTF-8 characters correctly when used in Unix, but they work in Windows.
    // So we need to do as follows. @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675396/1710782
    return $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$str='<a href="http://localhost/mytest/">internal</a>
<a href="http://localhost/mytest/go/hostgator">internal cloaked link</a>
<a href="http://cnn.com">external</a>';

function test($x){
  if (preg_match('@localhost/mytest/(?!go/)@i',$x[0])>0) return $x[0];
  return 'rel="nofollow" '.$x[0];
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/href=[\'"][^\'"]+/i', 'test', $str);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another solution which has whitelist option and add tagret Blank attribute.
And also it check if there already a rel attribute before add a new one.

```
function Add_Nofollow_Attr($Content, $Whitelist = [], $Add_Target_Blank = true) 
{
    $Whitelist[] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    foreach ($Whitelist as $Key => $Link) 
    {
        $Host = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $Link);
        $Host = "https?://". preg_quote($Host, '/');
        $Whitelist[$Key] = $Host;
    }

    if(preg_match_all("/<a .*?>/", $Content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) 
    {
        foreach ($matches as $Anchor_Tag) 
        {
            $IS_Rel_Exist = $IS_Follow_Exist = $IS_Target_Blank_Exist = $Is_Valid_Tag =  false;
            if(preg_match_all("/(\w+)\s*=\s*['|\"](.*?)['|\"]/",$Anchor_Tag[0],$All_matches2)) 
            {
                foreach ($All_matches2[1] as $Key => $Attr_Name)
                {
                    if($Attr_Name == 'href')
                    {
                        $Is_Valid_Tag = true;
                        $Url = $All_matches2[2][$Key];
                        // bypass #.. or internal links like "/"
                        if(preg_match('/^\s*[#|\/].*/', $Url)) 
                        {
                            continue 2;
                        }

                        foreach ($Whitelist as $Link) 
                        {
                            if (preg_match("#$Link#", $Url)) {
                                continue 3;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if($Attr_Name == 'rel')
                    {
                        $IS_Rel_Exist = true;
                        $Rel = $All_matches2[2][$Key];
                        preg_match("/[n|d]ofollow/", $Rel, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
                        if( count($match) > 0 )
                        {
                            $IS_Follow_Exist = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $New_Rel = 'rel="'. $Rel . ' nofollow"';
                        }
                    }
                    else if($Attr_Name == 'target')
                    {
                        $IS_Target_Blank_Exist = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            $New_Anchor_Tag = $Anchor_Tag;
            if(!$IS_Rel_Exist)
            {
                $New_Anchor_Tag = str_replace(">",' rel="nofollow">',$Anchor_Tag);
            }
            else if(!$IS_Follow_Exist)
            {
                $New_Anchor_Tag = preg_replace("/rel=[\"|'].*?[\"|']/",$New_Rel,$Anchor_Tag);
            }

            if($Add_Target_Blank && !$IS_Target_Blank_Exist)
            {
                $New_Anchor_Tag = str_replace(">",' target="_blank">',$New_Anchor_Tag);
            }

            $Content = str_replace($Anchor_Tag,$New_Anchor_Tag,$Content);
        }
    }
    return $Content;
}
```

To use it:

```
$Page_Content = '<a href="http://localhost/">internal</a>
                 <a href="http://yoursite.com">internal</a>
                 <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
                 <a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">example</a>
                 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" rel="random">stackoverflow</a>';

$Whitelist = ["http://yoursite.com","http://localhost"];

echo Add_Nofollow_Attr($Page_Content,$Whitelist,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress decision:

```
function replace__method($match) {
    list($original, $tag) = $match;   // regex match groups

    $my_folder =  "/articles";       // re-add quirky config here
    $blog_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    if (strpos($tag, "nofollow")) {
        return $original;
    }
    elseif (strpos($tag, $blog_url) && (!$my_folder || !strpos($tag, $my_folder))) {
        return $original;
    }
    else {
        return "<$tag rel='nofollow'>";
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_nofollow_to_external_links', 1 );

function add_nofollow_to_external_links( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace_callback('~<(a\s[^>]+)>~isU', "replace__method", $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: A piece of code without any explanations is useless.

Answer (score -1):

a good script which allows to add nofollow automatically and to keep the other attributes

```
function nofollow(string $html, string $baseUrl = null) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
            '#<a([^>]*)>(.+)</a>#isU', function ($mach) use ($baseUrl) {
                list ($a, $attr, $text) = $mach;
                if (preg_match('#href=["\']([^"\']*)["\']#', $attr, $url)) {
                    $url = $url[1];
                    if (is_null($baseUrl) || !str_starts_with($url, $baseUrl)) {
                        if (preg_match('#rel=["\']([^"\']*)["\']#', $attr, $rel)) {
                            $relAttr = $rel[0];
                            $rel = $rel[1];
                        }
                        $rel = 'rel="' . ($rel ? (strpos($rel, 'nofollow') ? $rel : $rel . ' nofollow') : 'nofollow') . '"';
                        $attr = isset($relAttr) ? str_replace($relAttr, $rel, $attr) : $attr . ' ' . $rel;
                        $a = '<a ' . $attr . '>' . $text . '</a>';
                    }
                }
                return $a;
            },
            $html
    );
}
```

Comment: Please, don't post twice the same answer. The other question is a dup.

Comment: @Toto I corrected the post so please remove Reputation down !

Comment: @Toto Stackooverflow my blocked