# Functions.php to set all external links with rel:="nofollow"

Tags: wordpress

when i use the code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_nofollow');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_nofollow');

function my_nofollow($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]+/', 'my_nofollow_callback', $content);
}
function my_nofollow_callback($matches) {
    $link = $matches[0];
    $site_link = get_bloginfo('url');
    if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false) {
        $link = preg_replace("%(href=\S(?!$site_link))%i", 'rel="nofollow" $1', $link);
    } elseif (preg_match("%href=\S(?!$site_link)%i", $link)) {
        $link = preg_replace('/rel=\S(?!nofollow)\S*/i', 'rel="nofollow"', $link);
    }
    return $link;
}
```

only in the_content and the_excerpt the links get a nofollow attribute. How i can edit the code, that the whole wordpress site use this functions (footer, sidebar...)

Thank you

Comment: You're on the right track but you [shouldn't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You could do this with [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add rel="nofollow" to links with preg\_replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037592/how-to-add-rel-nofollow-to-links-with-preg-replace)

Answer (score 3):

a good script which allows to add nofollow automatically and to keep the other attributes

```
function nofollow(string $html, string $baseUrl = null) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
            '#<a([^>]*)>(.+)</a>#isU', function ($mach) use ($baseUrl) {
                list ($a, $attr, $text) = $mach;
                if (preg_match('#href=["\']([^"\']*)["\']#', $attr, $url)) {
                    $url = $url[1];
                    if (is_null($baseUrl) || !str_starts_with($url, $baseUrl)) {
                        if (preg_match('#rel=["\']([^"\']*)["\']#', $attr, $rel)) {
                            $relAttr = $rel[0];
                            $rel = $rel[1];
                        }
                        $rel = 'rel="' . ($rel ? (strpos($rel, 'nofollow') ? $rel : $rel . ' nofollow') : 'nofollow') . '"';
                        $attr = isset($relAttr) ? str_replace($relAttr, $rel, $attr) : $attr . ' ' . $rel;
                        $a = '<a ' . $attr . '>' . $text . '</a>';
                    }
                }
                return $a;
            },
            $html
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add your action in the full html buffer, once everything is loaded and filtered, not only in the 'content' area.
**BE VERRY CAREFULL WITH THIS** !!!! This action is verry RAW and low-level... You can really mess up everything with theses buffer actions. But it's also very nice to know ;-)
It works like this :

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'buffer_start' );  function buffer_start() { ob_start( "textdomain_nofollow" ); }
add_action( 'shutdown', 'buffer_end' );     function buffer_end()   { ob_end_flush(); }
```

Then do the replace action and setup the callback :
Juste imagine the $buffer variable as your full site in HTML, as it will load.

```
function textdomain_nofollow( $buffer ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '/<a[^>]+/', 'textdomain_nofollow_callback', $buffer );
}
```

Here is how I do the href checking (read my comments) :

```
function textdomain_nofollow_callback( $matches ) {
    $link = $matches[0];

    // if you need some specific external domains to exclude, just use :
    //$exclude = '('. home_url() .'|(http|https)://([^.]+\.)?(domain-to-exclude.org|other-domain-to-exclude.com)|/)';
        
        // By default, just exclude your own domain, and your relative urls that starts by a '/' (if you use relatives urls)
            $exclude = '('. home_url() .'|/)';
            if ( preg_match( '#href=\S('. $exclude .')#i', $link ) )
                    return $link;
        
            if ( strpos( $link, 'rel=' ) === false ) {
                    $link = preg_replace( '/(?<=<a\s)/', 'rel="nofollow" ', $link );
            } elseif ( preg_match( '#rel=\S(?!nofollow)#i', $link ) ) {
                    $link = preg_replace( '#(?<=rel=.)#', 'nofollow ', $link );
            }
        
    return $link;
        
}
```

It works well in my experience...
Q